# Difference in Days between first and last value in DateTime series

Tags: pandas, date

I have the following Dataframe with type DatetimeIndex and I want to calculate the number of days between the first value and the last value. For example: My desired result in this example would be 365.

```
Date
2015-09-01 08:00:00
  .
  .
  .
2016-09-01 08:00:00
```

I tried

```
df.head(1)-df.tail(1)
```

but this gives me the error:

```
AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'head'
```

Comment: That's not a DataFrame; that's an index. Either convert it to a Series (df.to_series()) or just use positional indexers: `df[0] - df[-1]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substract first value of index selected by `[0]` with last value `[-1]` and then call [`TimedeltaIndex.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.TimedeltaIndex.days.html):

```
a = (df.index[0] - df.index[-1]).days
print (a)
-366
```

EDIT:

if `date` is `index`, use:

```
number_of_days = (date[0] - date[-1]).days
```

Comment: If `df`  doesn't have an attribute `head`, I am pretty sure it doesn't have an attribute `index`  either.

Comment: Thanks!! but I get the same error AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndex' object has no attribute 'Index'. However, `number_of_days = (date[0] - date[-1]).days` does the trick

Comment: @FriedrichFranz that's because `df` is not a `DataFrame`.  It's an `Index`.

Comment: @FriedrichFranz - Thank you, I add it to answer.